# Running GRDB in a playground

Tags: swift, swift-playground, grdb

Being new to this programming environment, this instruction that appears at the top of the playgrounds shipped with `GRDB` leaves me not knowing how to proceed:

> To run this playground, select and build the GRDBOSX scheme.

Steps taken so far include going to the [github page](https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift)> clone or download > download zip > unpack.

I was able to run the sample projects on the simulator, but so far, not able to run the sample playgrounds.  I get:

```
error: no such module 'GRDB'
import GRDB
       ^
```

The [documentation for manual installation](https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift#manually) appears to cover adding `GRDB` to your project, as opposed to adding it to a playground.

Since the sample projects already work, I thought there would be an easy way to get the playgrounds working, but before I start trying things, and possibly doing it wrong, I thought I'd ask here for the right way to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GRDB author here. To run those playgrounds:

- Open the GRDB.xcworkspace workspace
- Select the GRDBOSX scheme in the menu next to the Run/Stop buttons on the top left of the window
- Select the Build command in the Product menu (Command-B)
- Select a playground in the source list on the left of the window (they are in the "Playground" folder at the top)
- Hit Run, and enjoy :-)

Comment: Hey Gwendal! GRDB is amazing! Me and my team worked the last 6 months working on an IOS app that uses GRDB has the underlying DB. We are live from around March and we are getting a high amount of traffic. We need to make some refactoring to our DB layer. Would you like to assist us as a paid consultant, help us find the weak spot and optimize DB-related tasks? Could be fun! Let me know :)

Comment: Hello Roi. You can send an email at gr(at)pierlis.com. Warning: in a couple of days, I'm going to be off in vacations for a few weeks!

Comment: Hey @GwendalRoué ! Thank you for replying. I have sent you a email from roi(at)uniqapp.com. Thanks!